# Can Several ListViews share the same FooterView?

Tags: android

I have two list views each visible at same time inside a ViewPager.  Do I need to create separate footer views for each?  Or could I share the same view as footer for both?  I need to add remove the view depending on statuses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot safely attach the same view at multiple points. Create a separate footer view for each list.

Comment: Ok.  How can I at least share the footer.xml layout?  I can inflate separately but what about identifiers?  Like say there is a button inside the footer how do I distinguish between the button in the separate view instances?  I am setting common onClickHandler(), and wanted to tell which button is in use.

Comment: Keep local references to the View instances you need as you inflate. As soon as you start dealing with lists it's usually not useful to make full-window findViewById calls to find anything in list item views, as many list item views also duplicate view IDs. Remember that a ListView footer view ends up being the same as any other item view - if it's not visible on-screen, it's not attached to the view hierarchy and will not be found by a findViewById call anyway.